# Swing time picker

Tags: java, swing, datetime

Im looking for a pretty and decent time picker component. There are a lot of alternatives for date picking on Swing but no for time.

I've seen nice Date/Time components picking on JQuery ( for example: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ ). There is something similar on Swing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Use [JSpinner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) with [SpinnerNumberModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest the **TimePicker** component of the [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker) library. The time can be chosen with the (default) "drop down" menu, with (optional) "spinner" style buttons, or both.

Fair disclosure: I'm the primary developer.

The TimePicker can be customized with optional settings. A few of the settings are the language (locale), default times in the drop down menu, fonts and colors, display/menu/parsing formats, 12 or 24 hour clock, seconds or nanoseconds precision, and so forth.

The library also includes the DatePicker and DateTimePicker components. All three components are easy to use. (They can each be instantiated with a single line of code.)

I've pasted screenshots of the components and the demo application below.

Project Home page: https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker .

[image: DateTimePicker screenshot]

( Click to enlarge the demo screenshot. )
[image: Demo screenshot]

Comment: Good to see new contributions in this area.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will like the ease of JCalendar. It offers a `JDateChooser`, a `JDayChooser` or a `JSpinnField`, written by Kai Toedter', available here: [JCalendar 1.4](http://toedter.com/jcalendar/).

[image: JDateChooser Example]

You can get your dates like this:

```
java.util.Date fromDate = jDateChooser1.getDate();
```

JSpinnField lets you set max and min values easily:

```
jSpinField1.setMaximum(59);
jSpinField1.setMinimum(0);
```

Comment: The link to JSpinField is dead.

Comment: Thank you! They have changed their site.

Comment: I've added a new component for this: [JHourMinuteChooser](https://github.com/javatlacati/jcalendar/blob/master/jcalendar/src/main/java/com/toedter/calendar/JHourMinuteChooser.java), let me know if you need seconds.